# Create dynamic links with JQuery - individual post id

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are quotes in a forum. I have to place a "quote-back-link" via JQuery or Javascript to the original post.

Inside of each blockquote is span tag with the class name "post_id". The ID of that span tag contains always the ID of the original post. In the example the span tag is at the end of each blockquote, but its also possible to place it on a different position.

```
<blockquote>
  <cite>Testuser said:</cite>
    <div>This is a test</div>
    <span class="post_id" id="123"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser2 said:</cite>
  <div>This is a test</div>
  <span class="post_id" id="1234"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser3 said:</cite>
   <div>This is a test</div>
   <span class="post_id" id="12345"></span>
</blockquote>
```

Is there any way that I can rewrite the Poster-Name that is always between

```
<cite></cite>
```

with a link to the original ID? The examples have to look like:

```
<blockquote>
  <cite><a href="/post-123.html">Testuser said:</a></cite>
   <div>This is a test</div>
    <span class="post_id" id="123"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite><a href="/post-1234.html">Testuser2 said:</a></cite>
 <div>This is a test</div>
 <span class="post_id" id="1234"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite><a href="/post-12345.html">Testuser3 said:</a></cite>
 <div>This is a test</div>
 <span class="post_id" id="12345"></span>
</blockquote>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The example looks incorrect. Second href should be `/post-1234.html`, right?

Comment: yes, I already fixed it. You are fast. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can simply acquire, for each `blockquote`, its child `cite` and its `post-id` value. Then, just replace the html with the desired one.

Side (but relevant) notes:

- You should always check whether a `<cite>` element exists.
- You should always check that there is at least one child element with `.post_id` class. If there is none, you should abort the override. If there is more than one, you should handle the case.
- I'm using some ES6 syntax below (mostly, I'm using the ticks to parse strings). Some browsers may not support it, so you may want to convert the code to make it compliant to the targeted javascript version.

Of course, none of the above happens in the sample, but it's worth mentioning that you should take care of that as well.

```js
$('blockquote').each(function(blockquote){
  // Find the <cite> element.
  var _cite = $(this).find('cite');
  // get the first .post_id's id attribute value.
  var _postId = $(this).find('.post_id').first().attr('id');
  console.log(_postId); // <-- just a side note. This will be a string. If you need to use such id, remember to make it numeric if you need to use it as a number. You can do that by doing Number(_postId) or, simply, +_postId.
  // Generate the new html by generating a new anchor with the desired link.
  var newHtml = `<a href="/post-${_postId}.html">${_cite.html()}</a>`;
  // Override the <cite> html.
  _cite.html(newHtml);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<blockquote>
  <cite>Testuser said:</cite>
    <div>This is a test</div>
    <span class="post_id" id="123"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser2 said:</cite>
  <div>This is a test</div>
  <span class="post_id" id="1234"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser3 said:</cite>
   <div>This is a test</div>
   <span class="post_id" id="12345"></span>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Unbelievable how fast you are. Thank you so much. Works like a charm. Will mark you answer as fixed when its possible. (6 minutes to go)

Comment: @LarsVegas well, it's actually just one of the possible solutions, I'm pretty sure there are cleverer and faster ones. Please take a look at the notes I wrote above, I highly recommend you to mark them before using that in production ;)

Comment: sometimes there are double quotes. Then inside of the blockquote are 2 cite tags. Is it possible to use always only the first one for a replacement? thank you

Comment: found it :) -> var _cite = $(this).find('cite').first();

Comment: @LarsVegas yup, just ensure the first one is always the one you're looking for. `_cite.length`, in case you don't add `.first` will hold the amount of elements found, in case you need it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS Way:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.post_id');

elements.forEach(e => {
  var testUserID = e.getAttribute('id')
  var newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.setAttribute('class', 'post');
newlink.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com/post-'+testUserID+'.html');
  newlink.innerHTML = 'test';
  
  
  var cite = e.parentNode.querySelector("cite")
  cite.appendChild(newlink)
})
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <cite>Testuser said:</cite>
    <div>This is a test</div>
    <span class="post_id" id="123"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser2 said:</cite>
  <div>This is a test</div>
  <span class="post_id" id="12222234"></span>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
 <cite>Testuser3 said:</cite>
   <div>This is a test</div>
   <span class="post_id" id="12345"></span>
</blockquote>
```

Something like that could be done like this. I suggest not using jQuery when not needed. So I believe you do not need that. Also if you need a more generic way I am pretty sure you can extend this.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is also a great solution :)

Comment: You are welcome. You have to be careful of many things but as a basic prototype works.